Disable logging of `exc_info` when raising `BadRequest`?
When a Http404 is raised, the log provides the relevant information but not the details of the exception
But when a BadRequest is raised, the log includes exc_info so it makes it look like something went wrong rather than standard error handling of bad requests. So is there a way to disable or modify this behavior?

I've set DEBUG to False and those logs still happen
